# is there a way to write this query as a non nested query?

Tags: mysql

```
select libro.titolo 
from libro 
where not exists( select * 
                    from materia 
                    where materia.titolo = libro.titolo
                );
```

that's my query. I can't find a way to write it with no nested queries inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause to check if there is not a successful join (the join is not successful in case there is no value on `materia.titolo` or other columns of `materia`).

```
SELECT libro.titolo 
FROM libro LEFT JOIN materia ON libro.titolo = materia.titolo 
WHERE materia.titolo IS NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3fc6fc8ea3c98939f715ae40ff4d3d0a)